# How to save a reference value to another record in NetSuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I've created a custom Transaction Body Field named "Created From" of type List/Record - Transaction

[image]

That I want to be have like the native NetSuite Created From fields. I have added this custom field to the Customer Refund form and when entering (or editing) the refund if I give a value of "Sales Order `#1234`" it saves correctly and becomes a link to the sales order. But when I try to set it using code

```
 customerRefund.setFieldValue("custbody_ifx_created_from", "Sales Order #" + salesOrderId);
 id = nlapiSubmitRecord(customerRefund);
```

This error is generated

> Error: INVALID_KEY_OR_REF
>   Invalid custbody_ifx_created_from reference key Sales Order #81388396.

How can I create a valid key or reference to another record?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of your custom field is `list/record`->`transaction`.  You need to populate it with the internal id of a transaction record.  That will allow you to submit the record.  When viewed through the UI, it will display the 'Sales Order# XXX' text as expected.

```
 customerRefund.setFieldValue("custbody_ifx_created_from", salesOrderInternalId);
 id = nlapiSubmitRecord(customerRefund);
```

Comment: How do I indicate the type of transaction when I set the field to the record's id field?

Comment: You don't need to.  Transaction internal id's are unique regardless of transaction type.  They're all 'unique' elements of the `List` -> `Transaction`